# Count number of files in directory

Tags: bash, unix

I don't know why this command count also directories as files:

```
nb_fichier_src=($(find "$file" -type f | wc -l))
```

In `$file` I have 51 files and 1 folder, but the output of my instruction is 52!!!
I want to count only the number of files in my folder. Any ideas of what is going wrong?

Comment: When you only run `find "$file" -type f`, do you see the folder too in the output?

Comment: find executes recursively by default...so please check if you have more file inside the one directory you have...it will find that also and add in your count....

Answer (score 2):

To take care of files with spaces and new lines in filenames better to use `find` command like this:

```
nb_fichier_src=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo . \; | wc -l)
```

Take note of `-exec echo .` which prints a single dot for each file found in current directory.

Comment: Since `-maxdepth` is a GNU extension, you might as well use the `-printf` extension as well (instead of `-exec`) to avoid forking a new process for every file found.

Comment: Actually I have `maxdepth` in my `find` on OSX but don't have `-printf`

Comment: Huh, never noticed that on the BSD `find` before.

Answer (score 1):

You could `test` over a glob loop of the directory.

```
num_files=0
for file in directory/*; do
    [ -f "$file" ] && ((num_files++))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
ls -l | grep -v ^d | wc -l
```

Note:

- grep: checks for any line beginning with "d" (indicating a directory), and discards that line (-v)
- wc: - do a count of the number of lines (-l) in the output of ls -l

Comment: if somone is just looking for file then this approach may give incorrect results if various other types of files are present in the directory ..eg. block device (starting with 'b'), character device (starting with 'c'), symbolic link (starting with 'l').

Comment: Plus, parsing `ls` is a bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid a recursive search use the maxdepth option:

```
nb_fichier_src=($(find "$file" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l))
```